# How do I produce this query?

Tags: sql

[Here is the populated table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKIgs.png)

How could I produce a query to list the number of projects (full details) of each type

In this case there would be one of each type obviously but I'm not sure how to produce this

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you had in mind?

```
SELECT ProjectType, COUNT(DISTINCT projectID) as ProjectCount FROM Projects GROUP BY ProjectType
```

Comment: I think it is going to search for the actual names eg. "Database" as the projectIDs for 2 Database projects will differ, if you understand me